# Help merge meshes. Boolean not an option

Tags: modeling, materials, modifiers, vertices

(Experienced but still a noob.)

I downloaded a 3DS object (a satellite) and I'm trying to edit it in Blender.

The mesh was one big object. I'm trying split it into separate objects, but in one instance, some vertices remained part of the wrong mesh. I dragged the stray vertices to the correct mesh (in the hierarchy), but now they are in two parts and I wish to combine them into one.

Every tutorial I've found online says to use the Boolean "Union" modifier, but nothing I've tried works. Either nothing changes, or use of the modifier is not allowed.

Two questions: 1) how do I combine split vertices into one mesh? 2) How can I turn the Materials I already singled out for textures into separate meshes so I can select them again?

(Note: As you can see, I still use older v2.79b as I've never gotten the hang of the new interface.)

[Blender files](https://mega.nz/file/2IUDCYjK#G5-fb-4F1f1_k3cWDtGXYmFpFNY_fWIi0ExZLPKqj5s)

TIA [image: split vertices]

Comment: Just something to think about: version 2.79b is more than 5 years old now. You are currently so outdated, that 13 newer versions exist. You are missing thousands(probably literally) of new features and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: The solution isn't to "merge" the meshes, it's to "Join" them.

To do this, first select the mesh(es) that you DON'T want to be the parent (Be in "Edit" mode with nothing selected. Select the submesh in the tree under the parent.) Then Left-click while holding the SHIFT key to also select the other meshes (in the model window, not the tree) you wish to join. The last mesh selected will be the parent.

Then, on the "Object" menu, select "Join". Done!

(I still would like a solution to how to make applied Materials selectable again.)